# getField method in C

Tags: c, bit

I working on a method that is suppose to return the value of the field. Sanity check example: if the field is three bits wide and unsigned, the result will be a value between 0 and 7, regardless of the actual position of the bits in value. If the value is signed, the result will be between -4 and 3. Furthermore, if the value is signed, it will be negative only if the left most bit of the field is 1. In this case, the field must be sign extended (i.e. make all bits to the left 1). What I have logically seems right to me but seems to be off.

On my test I get it right when it's 0:somepoint; I get fails when it's somepoint:somepoint

```
int getField (int value, int hi, int lo, int isSigned) {  
    int x = 0;
    //int result = 0;
    for(int i =lo; i < hi; i++){
        x |= (1 << i);
    }
    if(isSigned == 1){
        value |= ~x;
    }
    else{
        value &= x;
    }
    int finalresult = value >> lo;
    return finalresult;
}
```

Comment: Please provide example input and output, ideally with a `main()` method that shows how to use this function. Describe what happens when you run your code and how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
int x = 0;
for(int i =lo; i < hi; i++){
    x |= (1 << i);
}
```

you can do like

```
int x = ((1 << (hi-lo)) - 1) - ((1 << lo) -1);
```

or add/subtract additional 1 from (hi-lo) - it depends if *hi* bit is "in" or not.

Why?

```
 1            => 0000 0001
 1 << 5       => 0010 0000
(1 << 5) - 1  => 0001 1111
```

Also, negative numbers are in [U2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation, so if you want to negate number you need do 2 steps:

1. invert all bits
2. add 1

therefor `value |= ~x` isn't enough (you will *invert* the zeros, but not rest of it, and you still have to add 1). You can simply invert with `value ^= (-1)`. That's why the case **somepoint:somepoint** wasn't working.

I've wrote something like that:

```
#include <cassert>

int getField(int value, int hi, int lo, int isSigned) {
  int result = 0;

  assert(hi >= lo);
                                            // let say we are interested in folowing bits: 
                                            // (marked as 1)
                                            // value := 0001 1100
                                            // so:
                                            // hi := 5
                                            // lo := 2
                                            // and e.g.:
                                            // isSigned := 1

  isSigned = (value >> (hi-1)) & isSigned;  // isSigned will be 1 if (it was 
                                            // 1 and proper bit is set to 1)
                                            // ((0001 1100) >> 4) & 1
                                            //   0000 0001        & 1
                                            //   0000 0001
                                            // isSigned := 1

  value >>= lo;                             // move interested bits that they start at 0
                                            // ((0001 1100) >> 2
                                            //   0000 0111
                                            // value := 0000 0111

  hi -= lo;                                 // how many bits we want?
                                            // hi := 3

  isSigned &= (hi != 0);                    // hi == 0 <=> hi == lo 
                                            // => sign will be always 0 
                                            // 1 &= (3 != 0)
                                            // 1
                                            // isSigned := 1

  hi -= isSigned;                           // if the last bit should be sign-bit
                                            // don't evaluate it as value
                                            // hi := 2

  result = value & ((1 << hi) - 1);         // (1<<hi)-1 creates bit mask 
                                            // 0000 0111 & ((1 << 2) - 1)
                                            // 0000 0111 &      (100 - 1)
                                            // 0000 0111 &       011
                                            // 0000 0011
                                            // result := 3

  if (isSigned)                             // true
    return -result;                         // return inverted result
                                            // -3
  return result;                            // if false return result
}

int main()
{
  assert(0 == getField(0, 0, 0, 0));
  assert(0 == getField(0, 0, 0, 1));
  assert(0 == getField(15, 0, 0, 0));
  assert(0 == getField(15, 0, 0, 1));
  assert(0 == getField(15, 1, 1, 0));
  assert(0 == getField(15, 3, 3, 1));
  assert(0 == getField(0, 3, 0, 0));
  assert(0 == getField(0, 4, 0, 1));
                                        // (sign bit)[value bits]
  assert(1 == getField(1, 1, 0, 0));    // 000[1]
  assert(0 == getField(1, 1, 0, 1));    // 000(1)

  assert(3 == getField(15, 2, 0, 0));   // 11[11]
  assert(1 == getField(15, 2, 1, 0));   // 11[1]1
  assert(7 == getField(15, 4, 1, 0));   // [111]1

  assert(2 == getField(5, 4, 1, 0));    // [010]1
  assert(2 == getField(5, 3, 1, 0));    // 0[10]1
  assert(5 == getField(10, 4, 1, 0));   // [101]0
  assert(1 == getField(10, 3, 1, 0));   // 1[01]0

  assert(-1 == getField(15, 2, 0, 1));   // 11(1)[1]
  assert(0 == getField(15, 2, 1, 1));    // 11(1)1
  assert(-3 == getField(15, 4, 1, 1));   // (1)[11]1

  assert(2 == getField(5, 4, 1, 1));     // (0)[10]1
  assert(0 == getField(5, 3, 1, 1));     // 0(1)[0]1
  assert(-1 == getField(10, 4, 1, 1));   // (1)[01]0
  assert(1 == getField(10, 3, 1, 1));    // 1(0)[1]0
  assert(-2 == getField(12, 4, 1, 1));   // (1)[10]0
  assert(-2 == getField(10, 4, 0, 1));   // (1)[010]

  assert(-3 == getField(28, 5, 2, 1));    // 000(1) [11]00
}
```

There is no loop. 2 jumps (`(hi != 0)` and `if(isSigned)`) but for me VCv120 in release mode somehow handles the first one, so in code I get only `if()`. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

There is also no multiplication (`<<` - bits shift instead of multiplication times 2), and only 4 subtractions. Not sure which one would be faster... That one remaining jump...

One more time function (this time without comments)

```
int getField(int value, int hi, int lo, int isSigned) {
  int result = 0;
  assert(hi >= lo);
  isSigned = (value >> (hi-1)) & isSigned;
  value >>= lo;
  hi -= lo;
  isSigned &= (hi != 0);
  hi -= isSigned;
  result = value & ((1 << hi) - 1);
  if (isSigned)
    return -result;
  return result;
}
```

## Edit

I've manage to slightly cleanup code:

```
int getField(int value, int hi, int lo, int isSigned) {
  assert(hi >= lo);

  hi -= lo;
  value >>= lo;
  value &= ((1 << hi) - 1);
  isSigned <<= (hi - 1);
  isSigned &= value;
  if (isSigned && (hi != 0)) {
    value -= isSigned;
    value = ~value + 1;
  }
  return value;
}
```

but generated asm has 2 jumps...

1. **if (isSigned**
2. **&& (hi != 0))**

## Edit 2

In this version:

```
int getField(int value, int hi, int lo, int isSigned) {
  assert(hi >= lo);

  hi -= lo;
  isSigned &= (hi != 0);
  value >>= lo;
  value &= ((1 << hi) - 1);
  isSigned <<= (hi - 1);
  isSigned &= value;
  if (isSigned) {
    value -= isSigned;
    value = ~value + 1;
  }
  return value;
}
```

is only one jump.